# Videos captured from an iPhone camera appear to be rotated by 90 degrees by OpenCV? How do I get around this?

Tags: c++, opencv, video, computer-vision

I shoot video from iPhone and convert each frame from colour to gray scale, however, the videos appear to be rotated by 90 degrees in OpenCV (4.1, C++)

the same issue doesnt show up on MATLAB or on VLC player (when I check)

Sample code

```
   // frame
    Mat current_frame;
VideoCapture capture("file_name.mov");

// Check - video file does not open for reading
if (!capture.isOpened())
    throw "Error when reading steam_avi";
capture >> current_frame;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rachit,

Phone cameras can record videos in four possible orientations: 
landscape - camera to the left
landscape - camera to the right
portrait - camera at the top
portrait - camera at the bottom.

In each of these cases, a rotation flag is encoded into the video and it is upto the decoder to honour the flag and perform the suitable rotation when reading. I believe this is done for faster encoding performance.

MATLAB definitely honours this on Windows 10.

Windows 7 on the other hand does not honour this flag and you will see rotated videos. As MATLAB appears to use the Windows frameworks for reading, it will be rotated in MATLAB too.

Hope this helps.

Dinesh

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Dinesh, your reply perfectly correlates with what I see with MATLAB on Windows 10. I think Apple exposes API that this rotation flag details included in.